# Amazon S3, Require Credit Card?

Tags: amazon, amazon-s3

I am registering to Amazon S3, but it says that a credit card is required upon registration. My purpose is to create a dummy account where I can test the amazon S3 for development.

Is there anyway to register without using a credit card? Or Is there any place where I can test for development?

Comment: You have to register a card. Check here, this might cheer you up (see accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525106/is-there-a-free-alternative-to-amazon-s3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a credit card, but as long as you don't use it "too much" you should be within the [Free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/). You get 5GB, of storage, 2,000 PUT requests, 20,000 GET requests.

Comment: Thanks, okay so amazon really needs a valid credit card information. I am actually thinking of ways to get through that. I checked on FakeS3 but I am not sure if thats they other way to go. Anyway, thanks.